# how to delete a php file using php?

Tags: php, unlink

I want to delete another php file from the server using unlink() function:

```
unlink('../classes/methods.class.php');
```

but I get a permession denied warning . although i made chmod 777 to that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chmod - **attempt** to change permission of file or directory.

You are most probably not permited to chmod file (if you have tried to change permittions trough PHP  ) or to unlink since you are not file owner.
See about file ownership, not just permittions.

Comment: You were right ... chown nobody:nogroup -R <path> solved the problem .
thanks !